# Timestamp Macro switched to different time source

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a timestamp macro that gives the current date and time at the point in which it is ran. I also have two cells that show the Stock Exchange Date and time. I need the timestamp macro to return the current date and time given in those two cells. I am lost on how to change it in my current macro. Below is what I currently have.

```
Sub TimeStamp()
'
' TimeStamp Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+T
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The first image is the information I need it to return  (L1 and N1) currently it returns the information in the second image

[image]

[image]

Tried to be as helpful as I can, still learning VBA. Hope it's a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using. Works perfectly.

```
' Following Inputs Exchange Date (L1) and Time (N1) into next available cell in column A
With ActiveSheet
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Value = Application.Evaluate("CONCATENATE(L1,N1)")
        .WrapText = False
    End With
End With
```